# Hide a path node on nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following url:

```
http://example.com/dr/2015/10/pic.jpg
```

where `2015/10/pic.jpg`is dynamic: 2015 is the year, 10 is the month number and pic.jpg a file name. Every time an image is sent, the year and month folders are created as the current date.

I would like to remove the node "dr" of the url, like the example below:

```
http://example.com/2015/10/pic.jpg
```

I found this question, which is the closest to what I need:
https://superuser.com/questions/435916/nginx-rewrite-rule-to-remove-path-node

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
    location = /pic.jpg {
        root /var/www/example.com/dr;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /pic.jpg;
    }
```